# Efficient Method to Change Row Values Based on Multiple Row Values

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe as follows,

```
    year    state   candidate   candidatevotes
0   1976    Alabama Carter, Jimmy   659170
1   1976    Alabama Ford, Gerald    504070
7   1976    Alaska  Ford, Gerald    71555
8   1976    Alaska  Carter, Jimmy   44058
11  1976    Arizona Ford, Gerald    418642
```

Here I need to  add a binary column, based on the winner of each state. For e.g Winner of the Alabama is Carter, Jimmy. Therefore the output should be looked like this.

```
        year    state   candidate       candidatevotes  winner
    0   1976    Alabama Carter, Jimmy   659170           1      
    1   1976    Alabama Ford, Gerald    504070           0
    7   1976    Alaska  Ford, Gerald    71555            1
    8   1976    Alaska  Carter, Jimmy   44058            0
    11  1976    Arizona Ford, Gerald    418642           1
```

What is the most efficient method for the above operation ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We usually do `transform`, you can add the `astype(int)` at the end conver the bool to int

```
s=df.groupby(['year','state']).candidatevotes.transform('max')
df['winner']=df.candidatevotes==s
df
Out[40]: 
    year    state     candidate  candidatevotes  winner
0   1976  Alabama  Carter,Jimmy          659170    True
1   1976  Alabama   Ford,Gerald          504070   False
7   1976   Alaska   Ford,Gerald           71555    True
8   1976   Alaska  Carter,Jimmy           44058   False
11  1976  Arizona   Ford,Gerald          418642    True
```